# Firefox doesn't show paths referenced by the use element + xlink:href attribute

Tags: firefox, svg, href, xlink

I have defined some `path` elements in a paths.svg file (https://gist.github.com/amirteymuri/42a64256c27824816f4f4c3b670bcb3d, please open as raw text).
This work fine when i open the file.svg (shown in below code) with inkscape but not with firefox (also in the Mirage the referenced paths are not shown):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" height="100" width="100">
  <use xlink:href="./glyph-paths.svg#117"
       transform="scale(0.01, 0.01) translate(200, 500)"/>
</svg>
```

I understand that `xlink:href` has been deprecated and the new version `href` should be used instead, however changing the `xlink:href` to `href` in file.svg causes everything to disappear so that even in inkscape i have none of the referenced paths anymore. Can someone give me possibly more information?

*Edit @Robert Longson*

This is the file named haydn.svg where i have imported some of my glyphs as paths (for the sake of simplicity i have included here only one of the paths which i am going to use):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
 <path transform="translate(0 0) scale(1 -1)" id="rests.2" d="M80 398c50 -68 90 -118 143 -184c6.22621 -7.92426 9.24864 -16.1689 9.24864 -24.7339c0 -6.56702 -1.77679 -13.3224 -5.24864 -20.2661c-19 -36 -40 -50 -69 -79c-10.4374 -10.8389 -14.9122 -26.0289 -14.9122 -42.9176 c0 -25.1817 9.94817 -54.1399 24.9122 -78.0824c40 -63 65 -107 104 -160c2.19052 -2.98708 3.11205 -6.05347 3.11205 -8.94647c0 -8.00267 -7.0515 -14.6785 -13.7996 -14.6785c-3.0625 0 -6.0625 1.375 -8.3125 4.625 c-18.7932 27.2501 -46.4159 62.4468 -87.0167 62.4468c-2.60722 0 -5.26795 -0.14514 -7.9833 -0.446846c-37.3002 -3.82566 -78.2594 -24.1165 -78.2594 -59.1228c0 -34.3572 13.2203 -53.8112 29.2594 -80.8772c1.90983 -3.24671 2.72542 -6.16515 2.72542 -8.67173 c0 -6.11404 -4.85254 -9.77763 -10.5138 -9.77763c-4.17048 0 -8.77986 1.98813 -12.2116 6.44936c-49 63 -97 106 -104 176c-0.304 2.7968 -0.452741 5.54555 -0.452741 8.24286c0 41.6664 35.4927 71.0611 82.4527 75.7571 c3.25176 0.309691 6.33568 0.451543 9.24434 0.451543c15.8756 0 26.5299 -4.22577 30.7557 -8.45154c6.0717 -5.31274 12.2874 -7.31334 17.2809 -7.31334c6.07303 0 10.3383 2.95907 10.3383 6.51795c0 1.22609 -0.506256 2.52338 -1.61926 3.79539 c-40 43 -69 91 -113 127c-9.72408 8.00806 -15.5219 22.5599 -15.5219 37.1052c0 10.8833 3.24596 21.7629 10.5219 29.8948c22 24 57 47 79 66c16.7435 14.9495 23.8322 33.1173 23.8322 52.5788c0 13.0839 -3.20398 26.7525 -8.83224 40.4212c-12 30 -23 48 -41 80 c-8 14 5 20 12 10z"/>
```

I then a calling from another file in the same directory the `"rests.2"` by using the `use` element (so there is no server etc., but i am wondering because not only the path isn't shown in FireFox, but i get the same behavior on GIMP and Geeqie. In fact only Inkscape is showing the used path, by `xlink:href`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="210.00000mm" height="297.00000mm">

  <use xlink:href="haydn.svg#rests.2"
       transform="translate(200 200)
          scale(0.1)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape does not support the href attribute, only the (deprecated) xlink:href. So it's not you, it's just Inkscape.

When I create  elements in Inkscape, I manually create an href attribute to match the xlink:href, because it's easier to manipulate href with JavaScript than xl;ink:href.

Whether you keep the xlink:href in the final file is up to you, and whether you need to put the file back into Inkscape again.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox's security model does not allow one local file to reference another local file. This due to a [privacy/security fix in firefox 68](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2019-21/#CVE-2019-11730). This is true regardless of whether you use href or xlink:href

You'll find such remote references do work in Firefox if you use a webserver to serve the files over http or https.

Comment: But why then are the referenced `use`d paths also not shown in other svg viewers like Gimp etc.? So far it could only be shown in Inkscape.

Comment: Also when trying to convert the result to PDF, no other convertors (including some online convertors) can convert the `use`d paths. It doesn't make also any difference if i change `xlink:href` to `href`.

Comment: I don't see why any of these comments are relevant to your question which is that use with local files has an issue on Firefox. That issue being that the Firefox security model does not permit it.